# Ошибка при повторном запуске TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python

Проблема
Код работает ровно один первый запуск (когда создает файл для записи результата, перечень корневых папок)
Последующие запуски выдают ошибку
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
Буду благодарен за помощь "чайнику".
Спасибо

```
import os
from os import path
import pickle

def def_list_dir():
    list_dir = os.listdir()
    return list_dir

while True:
    print('6 сохранить содержимое рабочей директории в файл')

    choice = input('Выберите пункт меню: ')
    if choice == '6':  # сохранить содержимое рабочей директории в файл
        print(f'__print1_ {def_list_dir()}')
        print(f'__print2_ {type(def_list_dir())}')
        if os.path.exists('fold_file_spis.txt'):
            with open('fold_file_spis.txt', 'rb') as f:
                fold_file = pickle.load(f)
                print = (fold_file)
        spis_papok = ''
        spis_file = ''
        for item in def_list_dir():
            if os.path.isdir(item) == True:
                spis_papok += item
            else:
                spis_file += item
            print(spis_papok, spis_file)
        with open('fold_file_spis.txt', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump((spis_papok, spis_file), f)

    elif choice == '12':
        break
    else:
        print('Неверный пункт меню')
```

Comment: текст стека ошибки должен быть указан в вопросе полностью.

Comment: И зачем это `print = (fold_file)`? :)

Comment: @gil9red Да, скорее всего в этом дело, там кортеж читается из файла в `fold_file` )

Comment: Благодарю Вас за комментарий.

Comment: Исправляюсь, привожу полный текст ошибки: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gmavi\PycharmProjects\Consol_file_manager\HT_package\proverka.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(spis_papok, spis_file)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: Касательно второго вопроса: "И зачем это print = (fold_file)? :)", да это проверка что содержится в создаваемом файле (по условию задания) - fold_file = pickle.load(f) , строкой выше.  Спасибо!

Comment: Ну вот просто уберите оттуда знак `=`: `print = (fold_file)` -> `print(fold_file)`. Сейчас вы получается поменяли встроенную функцию `print` на какой-то левый объект, в питоне так можно делать, в результате получаются вот такие загадочные ошибки.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Большое спасибо #CrazyElf.

Comment: Также благодарю #gil9red за ответ, его ответ был верным. Спасибо!